# ESLint: Parsing Error: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint, flowtype

I'm trying to use ESLint with Flow, but when I test it out in my file ESLint doesn't detect that I'm using static types.

```
var str: number = 'hello world';
```

What can I install or how can I make my linter ignore this? The colon, specifically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [babel-eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-eslint) as parser in .eslintrc:

```
"parser": "babel-eslint",
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Question: if I use the babel parser am I going to be missing out on anything that comes with the original parser?

Comment: We have been using it for a while on your flowtype + react project and I haven't noticed anything breaking. babel-eslint is widely used.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need babel, you can just use [typescript-eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/parser).